# Why does an induction motor not have the maximum torque when it is locked?

Tags: motor, ac

In theory the maximum current induced at rotor must be when the rotor is locked hence the force is  B.I.L it must produce the max torque.
But why torque is not maximum when it is locked but it is maximum at a point called breakdown torque?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the equivalent circuit of an induction motor:

[image]

Torque is proportional to the amount of power dissipated by the 'rotor running resistance' element, which varies as a function of slip.

To maximise torque, we must maximise the power dissipated in the rotor resistance. As per the [maximum power transfer theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_power_transfer_theorem), this occurs when the impedance of the 'load' (the rotor resistance) is equal to the resistance of the 'source' - meaning the equivalent impedance of everything else, seen looking back from the rotor resistance.

If the slip is zero (locked rotor) then the rotor resistance will be too low for maximum power transfer.

The book [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjGeJ.png) by Sarma, section 7.4 *Polyphase Induction Machine Performance*, explains this in complete detail. Expressions for maximum torque, and speed at maximum torque, are given. I highly recommend this book as a comprehensive treatment of induction motor theory.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjGeJ.png) Sarma, Mulutkula S, *Electric Machines - Steady State Theory and Dynamic Performance* (1985)

Comment: What do you mean by rotor resistance? Is that a theoretical concept? Or you mean rotor impedance?

Comment: The rotor resistance has two parts: a resistance due to the material resistivity of the rotor conductors, and a variable 'resistance' representing the work the motor is doing on the load.

Comment: For further questions, I would highly encourage you to find a copy of the book by Sarma, which should be in any reputable university library.

Comment: @Andy aka had a comment above and i asked a question. what do you think about this:"when the rotor is locked, you are saying: the flux change will be maximum(which will generate higher voltage on rotor) but at the same time the frequency also will be maximum and it will increase the impedance of the rotor which inturn will have decreasing effect on current. is that right what i understood from your words? if so i have a problem to understand this "rotor is a shorted inductor". is that true? i thought only the stator has windings and "rotor is just shorted bars. does rotor acts as an inductor?

Comment: I think you should go find a copy of the book by Sarma.

Answer (score 2):

When an induction motor has its rotor locked, the "slip frequency" is at its highest. Given that the rotor is a shorted inductor that receives "slip frequency" as part of the induction process, the inductive reactance is highest and the current in the rotor is going to be non-maximum.

Comment: This is actually not quite right. It's true that the inductor's impedance increases with slip - but the voltage induced in the rotor is proportional to slip. Once all the quantities are referred to the stator side of the circuit, the impedance increases cancels the voltage increase, and the rotor leakage reactance is independent of slip.

Comment: @Andy aka: so when the rotor is locked, you are saying: the flux change will be maximum(which will generate higher voltage on rotor) but at the same time the frequency also will be maximum and it will increase the impedance of the rotor which inturn will have decreasing effect on current. is that right what i understood from your words? if so i have a problem to understand this "rotor is a shorted inductor". is that true? i thought only the stator has windings and rotor is just shorted bars. does rotor acts as an inductor?

Comment: Yes, the rotor is a shorted inductor.

Answer (score 0):

The rotor current is highest when the rotor is locked and the forces acting on the rotor are greatest, but no all in the right direction. Imagine a rotor with superconducting bars. The stator flux would be strongly repelled by the flux from the current in the rotor and never allowed to enter the rotor, so the rotor would be producing an equally strong 'like' pole both before and after the stator pole passed over, so it would be pushed forward in front and backward behind. The net force would be straight down towards the shaft. Normally, the flux peaks as the stator pole passes over and the current reverses, producing an opposite pole which is attracted to the passing pole, so the section of rotor in front is pushed and the section behind is pulled, producing torque in the forward direction. If a low resistance high efficiency rotor is locked, the high current repels the rise in flux so much that it doesn't peak, and is still repelling the stator pole a bit until slightly after the centre of the pole has passed, producing some reverse torque which reduces the net torque. When loaded correctly, the slip speed is slower, giving more time for the rotor flux to peak. With a high resistance rotor you get more starting torque because the flux peaks quickly, so in either case even though the rotor current is less, all of the torque, or at least most of it, is in the right direction.